# How do I justify a plain text in HTML so that it stretches across the whole screen?

Tags: html

How do I justify a plain text in HTML so that it stretches across the whole screen?

The text looks like this:

1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6

I want it to completely stretch out to the right side of the screen. Like so (All the digits should be on the same line though):

[image: result]

No if's but's and when's, the list should be properly stretched out to cover 100% of the screen area. (Again: all the digits should be on the same line though)

Possible or not and if so, how? I assume using CSS. If there is a really easy way to do this I am not aware of it. I do NOT want to use tables, divs or spans.

I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: I doubt that is possible just with the given markup. What magic should take care to create _two_ rows in your desired outcome?

Comment: The only option I see here is to use some client side logic (so javascript) to replace that "plain text" sequence into markup which then can be styled by means of css. But that is a horrible approach.

Comment: @arkascha, yes. I'm not sure if it's possible. HTML/CSS is weird in this respect. It's 2016 and it's not capable of doing a simple thing like this which Word running on a 1999 machine could do in a mouse click. I mean there should be an easy way to do this. Like align justify which actually works. You could say that seemingly CSS align justify is really lacking this future and that's not impressive. So, if there is a way to do this that anyone know of let me know, it would be tres cool.

Comment: The combination of HTML and CSS is not weird at all. The issue here is that you try to use it for a task they are not designed for. A word processor indeed can solve that task _because it is what the word processor has been designed for_. You compare two totally different things. HTML is a language to structure text. You insist that there should be an option to style _unstructured_ text. That does not make any sense at all. Sorry.

Comment: But it is possible to style unstructured text in CSS by styling the <pre> tag. Also, because HTML/CSS are used to present text, this feature should exist as it is a useful way to present text. The combination of HTML and CSS is not weird to me - the absence of this feature and others are. Obviously I am aware that Word and HTML/CSS are two different things, but a styling feature is a styling feature regardless of environment.

Comment: Styling unstructured text does not make sense at all. It is against the whole idea behind a markup language. Why don't you simply convert that "plain text" sequence to something that _does_ make sense? There is no use for sophisticated styling options for some unstructured text when you have the elegant, working and mighty option to structure that text and apply proven and mighty styling rules to it. _That_ is a sane and straight forward solution for styling for the web.

Answer (score 0):

you should use flex layout model as described here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<div style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between;">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: And how does this generate multiple rows of numbers? Especially from a "plain text sequence" holding digits and some commas as it is stated in the question?

Comment: you can't style plain text. for commas just add them to the spans. there are many more options in flexbox model such as flex-wrap and you can set the width of elements. if you want an answer to style plain text - it is not possible

Comment: That is correct. Which is why in my eyes the above is not an answer to the question at all.

Comment: I don't like answer - it is impossible. and you shouldn't know if my answer cannot help to Vesa.

Comment: It is actually possible to style plain text as far as I know. Just set the rules for a <pre> tag using CSS.

Comment: @EduardVoid Then the above should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Vesa That still does not give you the separate rows, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha The rows do not need to be separated. I have updated the question to clarify. There should just be spacing between the numbers so that they stretch out across the whole screen.

Comment: OK, and how should a styling rule _guess_ that you want a padding between a comma and a digit, but not between a digit and a comma?